# Delete all empty spaces in specific column in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace

I am trying to delete all empty spaces in a specific column (currency column), because otherwise the imported values don't sum up correctly.

I tried this:

```
function cleaneuro() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H2:H996').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0.00\\ [$€-1]');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().replace(/\s/g, "")  // here it should happen
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate(); 

 };
```

But as so often, I seem to have a syntax error in the replace line...
any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "all empty spaces in a specific collumn"? Where do these empty spaces come from? Are they the result of a formula or do you actually mean a blank cell? Also add the textual error message.

Comment: Can you call  `replace()` on a RangeList?

Comment: @Diego `replace()` can't be called on a RangeList object.

Comment: Thanks @Rubén that's the issue then

Comment: @Diego IMHO the issue is deeper than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on a [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list). You need to loop through the returned ranges instead and use a [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder).

```
function cleaneuro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H2:H996').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0.00\\ [$€-1]');
  var ranges = spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    ranges[i].createTextFinder('\\s').useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith('');
  }
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate(); 
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reason you are not receiving the desired output is because the `replace` method you have used is typical for an object of type String and not of type RangeList.

Therefore, you can try getting the values from that range and you can also use this formula here in order to remove the empty spaces `VALUE.split(' ').join('')` instead for example

```
ranges[i].getValue().split(' ').join('')
```

#### Reference

- [Class Spreadsheet Apps Script - getActiveRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactiverangelist);
- [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).